# Nameerror using count function

Tags: python, count, nameerror

I am new to Python, and I have an assignment where I have few CSV files that contain cyber attacks information, I need to calculate (from each file individually) the number of attacks by counting the name of the attack in that file, the total are 5 files, all the files are in the colab notebooks folder, and the folder is mounted properly (because if I unmount or change the files names, I receive a different error), the first 2 files work perfectly, but the 3 to 5 return with nameerror, I will list the coding and results below.

They are pretty much copy and paste, and I even retyped each with no luck
I appreciate the help

Please note that it is referring to the (Adware) before the (.count), because when I change the CAPS of that word, the error changes accordingly, and I have tried all spelling options

```
file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Benign.csv")
incidents1 = BENIGN.count('BENIGN')
print('Number of Benign incidents:',incidents1)
```

Number of Benign incidents: 220 --------} correct result

```
------------------------------------
```

```
file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Ransomware.csv")
incidents2 = ransomware.count("RANSOMWARE")
print('Number of Ransomware incidents :', incidents2)
```

Number of Ransomware incidents : 1860--------} correct result

```
-------------------------------------------
```

```
file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Adware.csv")
incidents3 = Adware.count('ADWARE')
print('Number of Adware incidents:', incidents3)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-218-39a9858831f8> in <module>
      1 file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Adware.csv")
      2 
----> 3 incidents3 = Adware.count('ADWARE')
      4 
      5 print('Number of Adware incidents:', incidents3)

NameError: name 'Adware' is not defined
```

Please note that it is referring to the (Adware) before the (.count), because when I change the CAPS of that word, the error changes accordingly, and I have tried all spelling options

Comment: `Adware` isn't defined.
Where's the line with `Adware = `? If it's in this iPython notebook, I assume the cell hasn't been executed before this one.

Comment: fwiw , your first two examples should have produced NameErrors also - unless you haven't shown everything.

Comment: Thanks, but I shows everything, and this is what makes me wondering, why not the same if I am doing copy and paste

Comment: Adware is the word I want to count, which is in the adware.csv file, similar to Benign and ransomware are words in their respective csv filw